# basic calculator php error redirect to another page after clicking submit

Tags: php, html

I'm a php starter, and i don't know what's wrong with my code, it's supposed to be a simple basic calculator, first i started a server with the command `php -S localhost:4000` succesfully, i've been trying lots of code examples and they work fine, but this one doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="index.php" method="get">
        Number 01: <input type="number" name="num1"><br>
        Operation: <input type="text" name="op"><br>
        Number 02: <input type="number" name="num2"><br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
        </form>

        <?php

        $num1=$_GET['num1'];
        $num2=$_GET['num2'];
        $result="";
        $op=$_GET["op"];

        if ($op=='+') {$result=$num1+$num2;}
        if ($op=='-') {$result=$num1-$num2;}
        if ($op=='*') {$result=$num1*$num2;}
        if ($op=='/') {$result=$num1/$num2;}
        echo "Result = $result";
        ?>  

    </body>
</html>
```

and the error i receive whenever i click submit query, another page shows up:

it says; ping service in the title, and a little frame appears:

> Blocked by Content Security Policy
>
> An error occurred during a connection to [www.root-me.org](http://www.root-me.org).
>
> Firefox prevented this page from loading in this way because the page
> has a content security policy that disallows it.

I tried the code in an online php editor and same problem, is there something terribly wrong in my code, please help me! thank you

Comment: I think it's a problem related to encryption. Nowadays, most browsers don't allow to embed unencrypted content in a https page.

Comment: i don't know, other codes work just fine, i'm having a problem with just this script

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed
i changed the url from http://localhost:4000/site/ to http://localhost:4000/site/index.php
so the problem was actually in the form action attribute for he didn't recognize the index.php file!
Thank you

Comment: If you want your form to submit to the same page it is on, you can omit the `action` attribute altogether. The default action is to submit to self.